# Difference between generic constraint and superclass/interface

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Maybe it's so easy that I can't get but... what is the difference between:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T item) where T : SomeType { ... }
```

and

```
public void MyMethod(SomeType item) { ... }
```

?